# nvd3 cumulative linechart. missing overall slope also huge line appearing

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am working with NVD3 (d3) Reusable charts library

http://nvd3.org/examples/cumulativeLine.html

> A fore-note: Apologies for missing statistical data (please ignore). My server has had several severe problems. What has happened is that I am left with large holes in the data where the recording has stopped and also almost all of my timestamp data has been wiped away so I have had to replicate it with 13 second intervals. I hope this does not effect the responses I receive as my attitude is to carry on and work until all the data gets written over with new complete data. thanks

Here is the link to my work: http://computerstudio.eu/cumulativeLineChart.html (the page will take about 13-30 seconds to load so it will be blank at first)

**My Questions**

Why is my data not sloping downwards unlike bitcoincharts(dot)com what is happening there? things seem to be oddly exaggerated!

Why do I have a diagonal line through my chart? (I might be backwards some how, I think, but I am not sure how as the chart is showing in the right direction/not flipped)

I think maybe the diagonal line through is causing the missing slope.

[image]

Thanks again

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the [Cumulative line chart](http://nvd3.org/examples/cumulativeLine.html) instead of a regular line chart?  The cumulative graph expects percentage change data.

Comment: Its because I am trying to do a log chart (I think). I am getting quite confused as to how stock quotes display the data ranges. I have tried many ways and I never see the data displayed as they do